# Cordova 4.3.0 Error: Please install Android target: "android-21"

Tags: android, cordova

I have a project that is running well with ripple emulator, but when i try to launch it on a physical Android device, I get the following error :

> Error: Please install Android target: "android-21".
>
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Android\android-
>   sdk\tools\android.BAT
>
> You will require:
>
> 1. "SDK Platform" for android-21
> 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
> 3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
>
> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

The device I'm using is on Android 4.2.2. The sdk installed on my computer is the 4.4.2 (API 19) : 
[image: android skd]

I don't understand why my app doesn't lauch on my device.

Comment: go to your project folder -> platforms -> android -> AndroidManifest.xml find something like `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` What do you see?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
I suppose i need to install the sdk21 then?

Comment: then update your sdk. Install v21 tools

Comment: Install Android 5.0.1 (API 21) or set to API 19 in config

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm simply compiling two existing answers, which are both required to solve the problem.

Go to

```
project folder -> platforms -> android -> AndroidManifest.xml
```

find something like

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

and change the `21` to `19`.

Then go to

```
project folder -> platforms -> android -> project.properties
```

and change

```
target=android-21
```

to

```
target=android-19
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm getting this error: android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:542: Unable to resolve project target 'android-21'

Answer (score 3):

You should also edit the file platforms/android/project.properties and input the correct target.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
 project folder -> platforms -> android -> AndroidManifest.xml
```

find something like

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

you will see it's targetSdkVersion is 21. make that 19 and run for now. To go with 21, update your android tools.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the following packages

1. Android SDK Platforms-tools (Latest)
2. Android SDK build-tools (Latest)
3. SDK Platform  (api 22)

For your reference please see the screenshot attached below[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found it was the name of the project which posed the problem because it contained special characters like '&'.

So I renamed my project with a simple name and it works very well now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow's policy is to be an English speaking site, so posts in other languages will be flagged for removal. I know enough French to edit your post to be English but normally this wont be possible.