# "Cordova run android" throws missing target error, even when dependencies are installed

Tags: android, cordova

I tried to run this command on command prompt

```
cordova run android --device
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Error: Please install Android target: "android-23".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: "C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
tools\android.bat"
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

when I open Android SDK Manager all these are installed

[image: Take a look here]

I tried the solution in this question : 
[Cordova 4.3.0 Error: Please install Android target: "android-21"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899691/cordova-4-3-0-error-please-install-android-target-android-21) but it doesn't work

how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys :

I solved my problem by deleting all files in

`C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

and I put under this location all files from

```
C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\android-sdk
```

Answer (score 2):

The SDK's you're looking at are not the SDK's you're building with.

The error message states opening the SDK's at `C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\`, while the screenshot displays the SDK's at `C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\android-sdk\`

**Option 1**: Make sure you open the correct SDK manager (indicated by the error message) and add the required dependencies.

**Option 2**: You could also change the SDK's used by Cordova by updating the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable from `C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\` to `C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\android-sdk\`

Answer (score 1):

Change the environment variable..

right click mycomputer -> properties -> advanced system settings -> click on advanced tab -> click on  environment variables (at the bottom) -> select path and click edit. -> under variable add "C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\android-sdk\" and click ok.

It will work . else post screen shot of the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a virtual device first. After the creaton you can use the command. Looks like you just need to add the device because all required SDKs etc are installed.

Description: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Comment: thanks for reply but I want to run my app in my smart phone(real) I can run it in virtual device